# What is the color used in Table View section head / footer text?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uicolor

This muted blue grey color is all over the place, and I can't find a convenience color that looks even remotely close.  Clearly I'm missing something obvious...

I'm trying to "fake" a stock look for a UIView that is my section footer for a UITableView.  Has anyone else had any luck?

My UILabel will also need a white drop shadow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how Apple takes the RGB values and converts them to float (it would seem it's not a simple VALUE / 255), but the values that I got which when using the eyedropper in Photoshop gave the same RGB values were:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:0.3025 green:0.3375 blue:0.425 alpha:1]
```

The other piece that has blown my mind, is that everyone got different RGB values! How does that happen?

Comment: It depends on the color space calibration of the devices the image passes through before you sample it. Colors are noticeably different between a Retina Display and my desktop monitor, and sampling them with Photoshop after gamma correction is almost guaranteed to have differing results. Your RGB is not my RGB.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, @warrenm. Am I safe to assume that if my eyedropper method gives the same RGB values for the "stock" and my custom text than I'm "safe" on the multiple device screens, or should I be totally obsessive about it and scrutinize it on the device? (of course the obvious answer is "if you're that much of a nut-ball") Maybe bigger question is: shouldn't there be a constant RGB value that we all can use for this common color?

Comment: For practical purposes, there should be (and probably is) a consistent value across devices running iOS. The trick is just realizing that you can't treat an eyedropped RGB value as canonical; it will probably wind up being a game of guess-and-check. Of course, if you were feeling industrious, you could build a throwaway project with the "stock" and "custom" controls side-by-side and a trio of RGB color sliders and tweak till you get a perceptual match :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the color used is [UIColor darkGrayColor].

Also, you can create your custom headers using

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

in the table view delegate.

Comment: Nope... not blue enough: http://yfrog.com/5t6v3p (and I'm trying to avoid doing customer headers, since they are "good enough")

Comment: Sorry, got confused. The RBG is (76,86,108). Also it has a white shadow with a vertical shift of 1px.

Comment: [UIColor colorWithRed:76/255.0 green:86/255.0 blue:108/255.0 alpha:1.0]

Comment: How are everyone's RGB values so different? I got R:59 G:68 B:90 !

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already taken a snapshot, you could use a color picker to get the colors.

- header: (0.37, 0.40, 0.52)
- footer: (0.28, 0.36, 0.64)